# Find and replace JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

The input is like this:

```
0030 0110 0030 0210 0030 0310 0030 0410
0030 0510 0030 0610 0030 0710 0030 0810
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
00 30 01 10 00 30 02 10 00 30 03 10 00 30 04 10 00 30 05 10 00 30 06 10 00 30 07 10 00 30 08 10
```

In other words, I want the output to be separated in bunch of two (hexadecimal) digits and only one line.

I tried with this:

```
const REGEX_FIND_2 = /(\w{2}(?! |\n|\r))|(\n)|(\r)/g;
const REGEX_REPLACE_2 = "$1 ";
```

Strangely it works in `Sublime Text 3` but in JavaScript it appends one more space between the lines like this:

```
00 30 01 10 00 30 02 10 00 30 03 10 00 30 04 10  00 30 05 10 00 30 06 10 00 30 07 10 00 30 08 10
```

Please note the extra space between `04 10` and `00 30`.

Comment: Replace spaces with blank space and then try agaiin

Comment: @Rajesh Could you please show an example?

Comment: The extra spaces you are getting could be extra spaces or new line characters. Hence first replace all spaces with blank value and then parse using your regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may repalce line breaks with a single space, and then insert a space in between each pair of digits:

```
s = s.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ').replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, "$1 $2");
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var s = "0030 0110 0030 0210 0030 0310 0030 0410\r\n0030 0510 0030 0610 0030 0710 0030 0810";
console.log(s.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ').replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, "$1 $2"));
```

In case you need to make sure only "whole word" 4-digit chunks are affected, use word boundaries: `/\b(\d{2})(\d{2})\b/g`.

Comment: The reason you got a double space at the end of the line is because there are both `\n` and `\r`, and thus, there were 2 replacements, `\r` -> " ", and `\n` => `" "`. You might use [`.replace(/(\w{2}(?![\n\r ]))|[\n\r]+/g, '$1 ')`](https://jsfiddle.net/9rkq81jk/), but it will still result in a trailing space that you will need to `trim()`, so why not simplify the regex and use the same amount of steps?

Comment: thank you. How couldn't I notice it :). I replaced `\d` with `[0-9a-f]` cause in a bigger example there would be digits like `ab64`. Casually the example doesn't include `a-f` digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

It needs single replace operation

```js
const str = `0030 0110 0030 0210 0030 0310 0030 0410
0030 0510 0030 0610 0030 0710 0030 0810`;

const result = str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\s+|$)/g,`$1 $2 `);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
text.split(' ').join('').split('\n').join('').replace(/(.{2})/g, '$1 ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only experience in .NET but I'll do my best to help you out.

Firstly, you can get rid of the white space:

```
var s = "0030 0110 0030 0210 0030 0310 0030 0410".replace(" ", "");
```

This will give you a string without spaces:

```
s = "00300110003002100030031000300410"
```

Then you can loop through the string characters, and for every two do what you want with them (this is done using a modulus operator (%) - every other incrimination of the loop will either produce 0 or 1 from the modulus. Every time you hit a '0', you're on a second pass (and you have your string)

```
var 2LengthCh;
var 1LengthCh;
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
if (i%2) = 0 {
//this gets hit every second pass
2LengthCh = 1LengthCh + s.charAt(i);
}
else{
//This gets hit every first pass
1LengthCh = s.charAt(i);
 }
}
```